# How do I stop Windows from cleaning my taskbar of icons to (Bitlocker) encrypted files?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, bitlocker

I have encrypted a partition of mine with Bitlocker. There are some icons in my taskbar that point to files/programs on this encrypted partition. After a few days, all of those icons are gone (the other icons remain). If I add them back, they will disappear again in a few days. How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Windows seems to do a cleanup of the taskbar every few days. Since the icons are just links, and they point to an unreadable path at boot time, they seem to be recognized as trash. To prevent this, you can revoke the necessary permissions (*Modify* and *Write*) from the user *SYSTEM* at the TaskBar directory.

- Open up the directory properties of *%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar*
- Go to the *Security* tab
- Click on *Advanced*
- If you have to, click on *Change permissions*
- Click on *Disable inheritance*
- If it asks, click on *Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object.*
- Double click on the *SYSTEM* user or select it and click on *View*
- Revoke the permissions *Modify* and *Write*
- Save everything and you're done

Comment: It looks like this won't help.